# Why are we interested in auto-homeomorphisms?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am studying extensions of auto-homeomorphisms over compactifications and have a question:

A homeomorphism between two different spaces tells us that the spaces are topologically indistinguishable. Then, why would we study auto-homeomrphisms which are homeomorphisms between one and the same space? What else about the space can the autohomeomorphism tell us?

Thank you for your insights!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may view this as extending the concept of symmetries (which would by auto-isometries instead of auto-homeomorphism) to a more general situation. E.g., a cube has a larger symmetry group than a general parallelepiped, and in fact the subgroup structure of the symmetry group of the cube compared to that of the tetrahedron can tell us how to obtain a tetrahedron by picking every other vertex. If you loosen the concept from isometries to homeomorphism you can get similar classifying insights for topological spaces (instead of metric spaces)

Answer (score 2):

You always have the identity as an automorphism, of course. And the inverse of an automorphism is also one, as is the composition of two. So they naturally form a group, and in some cases we can put a natural topology on that group and have a nice new topological group.

If there are many automorphisms, lots of points topologically "behave the same", a space $X$ such that for every $x,y \in X$ there is an automorphism of $X$ that maps $x$ to $y$ is called *homogeneous*. It implies that the automorphism group is "rich" or "large". Many natural spaces in topology, like $\Bbb R, \Bbb Q$, the irrationals, the Cantor set etc. are homogeneous and have interesting automorphism groups. Showing a space to be non-homogeneous (like the unit disk) can be a challenging problem.

Answer (score 1):

It will appear in many places naturally.

Example 1: If one point can be continuously moved to another point by automorphism.Then these two points have some common properties.

Example 2: Computing $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb C \cup \{\infty\})$ or $\operatorname{Aut}(\text{unit disk})$ is an interesting problem.